# Being late in sending back the signed contract

Tags: new-job, contracts

I had a job offer and to start the onboarding procedures my employer sent me a soft-copy of the contract by email. I signed it and sent it back by email.
The employer also sent me an hard-copy of the contract by normal post. The hard-copy had some other documents I had to fill and send back within a given date.
The problem is that I received the hard-copy only 2 days ago and I should have sent everything back yesterday. As I am still working at my current job (notice period) I did not manage to be on time with the delivery.

What to do? Would this negatively affect my future job?

Comment: If you are concerned reach out to the receiver and let them know you are mailing them ASAP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you manage to complete it today, you will be one day late. Since the time it takes for mail to be delivered can vary by more than a day, this probably won't even be noticeable.

If you are quite worried about it, just pay a little extra to send it by a premium mail service that can get it there the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Exceeding your deadlines before you even started the job doesn't make the best first impression, but it *should* be acceptable. I am not your future boss, though. People are different.

Accepting the work contract by email *should* be enough to form a valid work contract in *most* places (IANAL).

You might still want to give them a call to inform them that you are still on it and haven't forgotten about it yet.

Comment: If the company makes a big deal about failing to meet a one day turn-around for paperwork, while the OP is still employed elsewhere, *they* aren't making a great first impression either...